# Pass custom types in Dynamic module that imports FormlyModule and register default types

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, ngx-formly

I am using dynamic form module that imports FormlyModule (https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly) and define some default types/components that will be register when this dynamic module is imported. What i need is to have option to pass custom types outside of dynamic module (not just the types defined in config file form dynamic module) when import this dynamic module.

**Module structure**

[image]

**Dynamic Module**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AcUiModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormlySelectModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormlyModule.forRoot(FORM_CONFIG),
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    exports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormlyModule, FormlyBootstrapModule],
})
export class AcDynamicFormModule {
    static forRoot(config?: Partial<any>): ModuleWithProviders<AcDynamicFormModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: AcDynamicFormModule,
            providers: [
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

**dynamic-form-config.model.ts**

```
export const FORM_CONFIG: ConfigOption = {
    types: [
        {
            name: 'input',
            component: CustomInputFieldComponent,
            wrappers: ['form-field'],
        }
        ....
    ],
    wrappers: [
        {
            name: 'form-field',
            component: AcWrapperFormField,
        },
    ],
    validationMessages: [
        { name: 'required', message: 'This field is required' }
    ],
    validators: [{ name: 'emailvalidation', validation: emailValidation }],
};
```

**custom input field**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ac-input-field',
    template: `
        <input
            *ngIf="type !== 'number'; else numberTmp"
            [type]="type"
            [formControl]="formControl"
            class="form-control mb-2"
            [formlyAttributes]="field"
            [class.is-invalid]="showError"
        />
        <ng-template #numberTmp>
            <input
                type="number"
                [formControl]="formControl"
                class="form-control"
                [formlyAttributes]="field"
                [class.is-invalid]="showError"
            />
        </ng-template>
    `,
})
export class CustomInputFieldComponent extends FieldType {
    get type() {
        return this.to.type || 'text';
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, DynamicFormComponent],
    imports: [
        ...
        AcDynamicFormModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

As we can from usage at this point only types defined in config will be registerd by formly. I want to have options to pass additional types when i need, for example:

```
 AcDynamicFormModule.forRoute({types: [{name: 'picker', component: CustomPickerComponent]}),
```

it is possible somehow with this approach to define static forRoute/forChild method and there register those types in FormlyModule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer. We need to define forChild method in dynamic module that will register new formly types. If we want only defined to be register we will call just AcDynamicFormModule otherwise

```
 AcDynamicFormModule.forChild({types: [{{
            name: 'custom-comp',
            component: CustomTypeComponent,
            wrappers: ['form-field'],
        }}]})


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        FormlyModule.forRoot(AC_FORM_CONFIG)
    ],
    declarations: [
        ....
    ],
    exports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormlyModule, FormlyBootstrapModule],
})
export class AcDynamicFormModule {
    public static forChild(config: ConfigOption = {}): ModuleWithProviders[] {
        return [{ ngModule: AcDynamicFormModule, providers: [] }, FormlyModule.forChild(config)];
    }
}
```